# Calling object functions - python

Tags: python, object

In the following code, is there any difference between the last two lines, internally? Or is one just a abbreviation for the other one?

```
class Foo():
    def say(self, c):
        self.c = c
        print("Foo")

f = Foo()
Foo.say(f,"Speak!")
f.say("Speak!")
```

Comment: Internally there is no difference really. The outcome is the same.

Comment: Thanks, the duplicate link was actually what I was looking for.